# Predicted probability from multinomial logistic with clustered standard errors

Tags: r, logistic-regression, predict, multinomial

I would like to get the predicted values (with confidence intervals) for a multinomial logistic regression. I know this could be done with predict but in my case I have clustered standard errors in the following way:

```
multinom <- mlogit(Y ~0| X1+ X2 , data)
cl.mlogit   <- function(fm, cluster){
  M <- length(unique(cluster))
  N <- length(cluster)
  K <- length(coefficients(fm))
  dfc <- (M/(M-1))
  uj  <- apply(estfun(fm),2, function(x) tapply(x, cluster, sum));
  vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(fm, meat.=crossprod(uj)/N)
 coeftest(fm, vcovCL) 
}
cl.mlogit(multinom, data$group)
```

How I could use these results to get the predicted probabilities (with confidence intervals) for X1=1 and X2=0 for example and compare it with predicted probalities for X1=2 and X2=0. Also, how could I get a confidence interval for that difference? In stata prvalue can do this but don´t know if there is an easy way to do it in R.)